# How garbage collection works with data segment?

Tags: c, go, garbage-collection

For below Go syntax in function scope `f()`:

```
var fruits [5]string
fruits[0] = "Apple"
```

Below is the memory representation:

### [image]

My understanding is, string `Apple` gets stored in *data segment* and rest of the **six** string headers(ptr,length) gets allocated in *stack segment*.

---

For below code in function scope `f()`:

```
numbers := [4]int{10, 20, 30, 40}
```

Memory for `{10, 20, 30, 40}` gets allocated in data segment but not in stack segment for function scope `f`.

---

[image]

Go garbage collector cleans heap segment of a process.

Returning from function `f()`, *stack segment* pointer clears stack segment of function `f()`

---

Edit:
To understand, *value semantics* & *pointer semantics* in the aspect of  allocating strings,

How data segment memory(for string `Apple`) gets cleared after returning from function `f`?

Comment: It really boils down to what torek tells you in the first paragraph: There is nothing to know because it is not your business.

Comment: @Volker, that's not a good way of going about this. The author wants to know how Go works inside. That's perfectly reasonable and we should actually encourage such questions. Go can and will change internally but that just means the answers will be relevant to particular versions of Go. No need to shut people up and close their questions. Especially with made up reasons like "It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced."

Comment: @torek how did you generate main.f file? How to generate object code .o?

Comment: I compiled to a binary and ran a disassembler on the binary. Using `-buildmode shared` should get you a shared-object, if that's supported on your OS.

Comment: @torek Please comment on this code: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240081/recursion-max-of-integers-in-slice

Comment: I'm not on the codereview stackexchange site (though obviously I could be since it's a one-click thing to join ... what I mean is, I never look there).

Answer (score 3):

The language definition for Go does not describe actions in terms of segments, stacks, heaps, and so on.  So all of this is implementation detail, which might change from one Go implementation to another.

In general, though, Go compilers do live-range analysis for variables and use [*escape analysis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) to determine whether to allocate something in GC-able memory ("heap") or automatically-released storage ("stack").  String literals may, depending on too many things to count, be allocated at compile time as text and referenced directly from there, or copied to some data area that's either heap-ish or stack-ish.

Let's assume for argument's sake that you wrote:

```
func f() {
    var fruits [5]string
    fruits[0] = "Apple"
}
```

This function doesn't do anything at all, so it just gets elided from the build.
The string constant `"Apple"` appears nowhere at all.  Let's add a bit more so that it actually does exist:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func f() {
    var fruits [5]string
    fruits[0] = "Apple"
    fmt.Println(fruits[0])
}

func main() {
    f()
    fmt.Println("foo")
}
```

Here is some (hand-trimmed / cleaned-up) disassembly of `main.f` in the resulting binary.  **Note that the implementation will almost certainly be different in other versions of Go.**  This was built with Go 1.13.5 (for amd64).

```
main.f:
     mov    %fs:0xfffffffffffffff8,%rcx
     cmp    0x10(%rcx),%rsp
     jbe    2f
```

Everything up to here is boilerplate: the entry point for the function checks whether it needs to call the runtime to allocate more stack space, because it's about to use 0x58 bytes of stack space here:

```
1:   sub    $0x58,%rsp
     mov    %rbp,0x50(%rsp)
```

This is the end of the boilerplate: after the next few instructions, we will be able to return from `f` with a simple `retq`.  Now we make room on the stack for the array `fruits`, plus other space the compiler deems appropriate for whatever reason, and update `%rbp`.  Then we store a string header at `%(rsp)` and `%8%(rsp)` in order to call `convTstring` in package `runtime`:

```
     lea    0x50(%rsp),%rbp
     lea    0x35305(%rip),%rax        # <go.string.*+0x24d> - the string is here
     mov    %rax,(%rsp)
     movq   $0x5,0x8(%rsp)            # this is the length of the string
     callq  408da0 <runtime.convTstring>
     mov    0x10(%rsp),%rax
```

The function `runtime.convTstring` actually allocates space (16 bytes on this machine) for another copy of the string header, on "the heap", then copies the header into place.  This copy is now ready to be stored into `fruits[0]` or elsewhere.  [The calling convention for Go on x86_64 is a bit odd](https://dr-knz.net/go-calling-convention-x86-64.html), so the return value is at `0x10(%rsp)`, which we've now copied into `%rax`.  We'll see where this gets used in a moment:

```
     xorps  %xmm0,%xmm0
     movups %xmm0,0x40(%rsp)
```

These instructions zero out 16 bytes starting at `0x40(%rsp)`.  It's not clear to me what this is for, especially since we overwrite them immediately.

```
     lea    0x11a92(%rip),%rcx        # <type.*+0x11140>
     mov    %rcx,0x40(%rsp)
     mov    %rax,0x48(%rsp)
     mov    0xd04a1(%rip),%rax        # <os.Stdout>
     lea    0x4defa(%rip),%rcx        # <go.itab.*os.File,io.Writer>
     mov    %rcx,(%rsp)
     mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
     lea    0x40(%rsp),%rax
     mov    %rax,0x10(%rsp)
     movq   $0x1,0x18(%rsp)
     movq   $0x1,0x20(%rsp)
     callq  <fmt.Fprintln>
```

This appears to be the call to `fmt.Println`: since we pass an interface value, we must package it up as a type and pointer-to-value (perhaps that's why there is a call to `runtime.convTstring` in the first place).  We also have `os.stdout` and its interface descriptor inserted directly into the call here, via some inlining (note that this call goes directly to `fmt.Fprintln`).

In any case, we passed the string header, allocated in `runtime.convTstring` here, to function `fmt.Println`.

```
     mov    0x50(%rsp),%rbp
     add    $0x58,%rsp
     retq
2:   callq  <runtime.morestack_noctxt>
     jmpq   1b
```

This is how we return from a function—the constants 0x50 and 0x58 depend on how much stack space we allocated—and, after the label that the start of the function can jump to, the rest of the function-entry boilerplate.

Anyway, the point of all of the above is to show that:

- The five byte sequence `Apple` is not allocated at runtime at all.  Instead, it exists in the `rodata` segment known as `go.string.*`.  This `rodata` segment is in effect program text: the OS places it into read-only memory, if at all possible.  It's just separated from the executable instructions for organizational purposes.
- The `fruits` array never actually got used at all.  The compiler could see that, while we wrote to it, we didn't *use* it other than the one call, so we didn't need it after all.
- But a string header, by which one can find both the length of the string and the data (in that `rodata` segment), *did* get heap-allocated.

It didn't *need* to be, as `fmt.Println` is not going to save this pointer, but the compiler didn't spot that.  Eventually, the runtime gc will free the heap-allocated string header data, unless the program exits entirely first.

Comment: "copied to some data area that's either heap-ish or stack-ish." what? There's no other place really in the executable to put the data other than data segment. It could be put on the stack but that would be unusual. Maybe just as an optimization for very small string literals.

Comment: The string header allocation is there only because `fmt.Println` accepts interface type. Calling `fmt.Printf` which explicitly accepts string as its first argument will eliminate the allocation.

Comment: @creker: very small literals are precisely what I'm thinking of. Suppose you have 8-byte registers: you can create a 5-character string by putting the five letters into 5 of the 8 bytes, then doing a store into memory. Now you have the read-only bytes in memory and need only write the length (5) into a header, and you're good to go.

Comment: Obviously this writes 3 unwanted bytes, but perhaps that might be good for alignment and hence performance. Compilers sometimes do this depending on optimization directives.

Answer (score -1):

> Memory for {10, 20, 30, 40} gets allocated in data segment but not in
>   stack segment for function scope f.

No, it's still gonna be allocated on the stack. `[4]int` is an array type. It's a value type. `int` is a value type. So the whole array would be on the stack, GC wouldn't need to deal with it.

But if something is allocated on the heap (I guess that what you mean by data segment) then the GC would kick in. The internals are an implementation detail and may change in the future but to put it simply current version would just start from roots (global variables, stack, registers) and mark all the live objects. Everything that's unmarked would be collected.

Edit:
If we're talking about string literals in particular. Strings work similar to slices - it's a value type, struct with two fields - pointer to the backing array of bytes and a length. String literals are special, they actually point to read-only data segment that contains actual string contents. So at runtime no allocation occurs and GC has nothing to collect.

Comment: No I meant data segment as data segment that generally stores global variables. What about strings?

Comment: @overexchange, strings are like slices. It's a struct with a pointer and a length. The contents of string literal are indeed stored in the data segment. Why would GC be affected?

Comment: My question is... when execution flow returns from `f()` does the memory allocated for string `Apple` be unused? because no pointer is referring that memory area.

Comment: @overexchange, there's no memory allocated for it. The string bytes are in read-only data segment. String object is a value type allocated on the stack. It points to the data segment directly, no memory allocation required.

Comment: when string object on stack gets cleared after returning from f(), what happens to string bytes in read only data segment?

Comment: @overexchange, nothing. What can even happen to a read-only data segment?